# C++ Clearing std::list of structs in class destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

If I maintain a `std::list` of a defined structure ABC (NOT pointers to said structures) as a class variable in `class P`, and manually push_back ABC variables populated in various member functions of class P.

- do I need to still do a list::clear() in the destructor of the class? Won't the structures inside the list be deleted anyways when the object of that class is deleted/removed from the stack?
- will it be more efficient if I maintained a list of smart pointers to said structures (each push back may/may not involve copying- since we are just storing the pointer in the list)?

Comment: 1) No 2) You need to measure.

Comment: If you are looking for efficiency then you might want to use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list`.

Comment: welcome to SO. well formulated question!

Comment: @NathanOliver: Well, widely that depends on how he uses it, doesn't it. If he has many pushes and doesn't need random access, a list is quite an efficient container because it won't be relocated like a vector when the vector's capacity is exhausted.

Comment: @decltype_auto That was why it was just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks a lot everyone! 
I want to use a list because I don't need random access to an index, just want to push, pop from front and back and iterate at least for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the need for `list::clear()` see the other answers. I should add that if the destructor of `ABC` has no other explicit jobs to do, you may just omit it and the compiler will automatically generate it for you.

As to the way to populate the list. You want to avoid deep copies of large data. This can be achieved by [moving](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

```
std::list<ABC> list;
ABC big(data_needed_for_constructing_ABC);
list.push_back(std::move(big));
```

provided `class ABC` has an efficient move constructor (which may be automatic if it's memory management uses standard functionality such as `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`).

You may also construct the new list element directly into the list

```
std::list<ABC> list;
list.emplace_back(data_needed_for_constructing_ABC);
```

when no temporary object `ABC big` ever exists.

Finally, if you cannot move the object efficiently and you want to have another copy of the object somewhere else, you may consider `std::list<std::shared_ptr<ABC>>`. However, that is only sensible if there is no clear ownership.

Comment: Given the move ctor is very cheap, which code would you prefer?

Comment: doesn't matter then. If you want to do something to the `ABC obj` before adding it to the list, use the first version, otherwise the second one is slightly faster.

Comment: I premised that it it doesn't matter much in terms of efficiency. I would however consider the first one more expressive, because there's an explicit ctor call and explicit rvalue construction; whereas the latter does its work behind the scenes; although `emplace_` is an expressive mnemonics, after all it it just an ordinary function, not a special function like a ctor that is visible in the code.

Comment: @decltype_auto That's just a matter of taste/opinion. I find `emplace` as expressive as an explicit constructor call, because I *know* that it will call the constructor. It is particularly useful for objects that cannot be moved nor copied.

Comment: It is certainly subjective. But in teams, one has to agree upon a common style, and it's good to know other developer's pov of such style questions for that process. Thanks for sharing your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need call clear explicitely. The destructor of `std::list` will take care automatically.

Whether switching to pointers is better or worse for performance depends on the size for your `ABC` data type. If it is huge, copying is expensive. In that case, avoiding copies should improve performance. On the other hand, if the objects are small, copying them is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

If your class contains a list as a data member then when an object of the class will be destroyed then the destructor for `std::list` will be called automatically that in turn will destroy all its elements.

You need not to call its method `clear` in the destructor of the class.